How to get the value of the files displayed, when not changed in vue js formdata?
My problem is when Im updating the images, and example, I dont do any changes on the images, ill stay it the same, i dont get the old or existing image. it really needs to change the photo before you can proceed. Anyone here who can help me, get the existing or old value of the image even if you dont change or select another image? Cause the user might only change the personal details but not the image. It says an error when you need to update. I dont know how to do it in vue js.
async updatebusinfo(e){
        e.preventDefault();
               
            if(!this.addinfo.busname){
            this.error.business_name = "Business Name is Required";
        }
        if(!this.addinfo.bustype){
            this.error.business_type = "Business Type is Required";
        }
          if(!this.addinfo.email){
            this.error.business_email = "Email is Required";
        }else if (!this.addinfo.email.includes('@')) {
             this.error.business_email = "Enter a valid email address";
                                    
                } else {
                  this.error.business_email = "";
                }

         if(!this.addinfo.contact){
            this.error.business_contact = "Phone is Required";
        }
         if(!this.addinfo.country){
            this.error.business_country = "Business Country is Required";
        }
         if(!this.addinfo.city){
            this.error.business_city = "City is Required";
        }
         if(!this.addinfo.barangay){
            this.error.business_barangay = "Barangay is Required";
        }
         if(!this.addinfo.tin){
            this.error.business_tin = "Tin is Required";
        }
         if(!this.addinfo.address){
            this.error.business_address = "Business Address is Required";
        }
        if(!this.addinfo.redirectweb){
            this.error.bus_redirectweb = "Web Redirection is Required";
        }
        if(!this.acceptTerms){
            this.error.terms = "You must agree to the terms and conditions";
        }

        if(this.clearance.length == 0){
          this.clearance = this.showbususer.clearance;
          console.log(this.clearance);
        }else{
            //this.error.clearance_err = false;
         console.log(this.clearance);
       }

       if(this.contractlease.length == 0){
          this.contractlease = this.showbususer.contractlease;
          console.log(this.contractlease);
        }else{
            //this.error.clearance_err = false;
         this.contractlease;
       }

        if(this.busregistration.length == 0){
          this.busregistration = this.showbususer.busregistration;
          console.log(this.busregistration);
        }else{
            //this.error.clearance_err = false;
         this.busregistration;
       }

        if(this.liabilityinsurance.length == 0){
          this.liabilityinsurance = this.showbususer.liabilityinsurance;
          console.log(this.liabilityinsurance);
        }else{
            //this.error.clearance_err = false;
         this.liabilityinsurance;
       }

        if(this.addinfo.busname && this.addinfo.bustype &&  this.addinfo.email &&  this.addinfo.contact && this.addinfo.country && this.addinfo.city && this.addinfo.barangay

            && this.addinfo.tin && this.addinfo.address) {

                        const config = {
                            headers: {
                                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                            }
                        }                    
                

                        const fd = new FormData();
                      
                             fd.append('clearance', this.clearance, this.clearance.name);
                        
                        
                         fd.append('contractlease', this.contractlease, this.contractlease.name);
                         fd.append('busregistration', this.busregistration, this.busregistration.name);
                     
                           fd.append('liabilityinsurance', this.liabilityinsurance, this.liabilityinsurance.name);

                        fd.append('busid', this.busid);
                       fd.append('busname', this.addinfo.busname);
                         fd.append('bustype', this.addinfo.bustype);
                          fd.append('email', this.addinfo.email);
                          fd.append('contact', this.addinfo.contact);
                          fd.append('country', this.addinfo.country);
                          fd.append('city', this.addinfo.city);
                          fd.append('barangay', this.addinfo.barangay);
                          fd.append('tin', this.addinfo.tin);
                          fd.append('address', this.addinfo.address);
                          fd.append('redirectweb', this.addinfo.redirectweb);


                        axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/updatebusiness", fd, config).then(response => {
                            console.log("response", response.data);
                            this.error.file_err = false; 
                        }).then(result => {
                            console.log(result);
                        }).catch(err=> {
                            console.log(err)
                            console.log(err.response.data.errors);
                            this.error.file_err = err.response.data.errors;
                        })                           
        }

    }
},

This the template
 <template>
<main class="flex-1 p-10 bg-white pb-20 mb-[30rem]" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div>
        <h1 class="font-bold" style="font-size: 35px; padding-bottom: 50px;">Business Information</h1>

        <h1 class="font-bold" style="font-size: 27px;">Makaturismo</h1>
        <h1 style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 300;">Shop</h1>

        <div class="flex justify-center">
            <div class="flex justify-start w-[50rem] flex-col">
                <h1 class="font-bold text-lg" style=" color: black; padding-bottom: 18px; font-size: 22px;">Business
                    Information</h1>


                <label for="business_name" class="pb-3" style="font-size: 17px;">Business Name</label>
                <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="busname" id="busname" placeholder="Makaturismo" v-model="addinfo.busname">

                 <!--  <p v-for="showbususers in showbususer" :key="showbususer">{{ showbususers}} </p> -->
          <!--    <p v-for="showbususers in showbususer">{{ showbususers[0]}}</p> -->
            
                 <label v-if="error.business_name" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_name}}</label>


                <label for="business_type" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px;">Type of Business</label>
                <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="bustype" id="bustype" placeholder="Shop" v-model="addinfo.bustype">
                <label v-if="error.business_type" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_type}}</label>

                <label for="business_email" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px;">Business Email Address
                </label>
                <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="email" id="email" placeholder="makaturismo@gmail.com" v-model="addinfo.email">

                <label v-if="error.business_email" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_email}}</label>

                <label for="business_contact" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px;">Business Phone/Telephone
                    Contact Number </label>

                <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="09234567891" v-model="addinfo.contact" @input="filterNumeric">
                <label v-if="error.business_contact" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_contact}}</label>

                <h1 class="font-bold text-lg pt-11" style=" color: black; padding-bottom: 18px;font-size: 22px;">
                    Business Registered Address</h1>

                <label for="country_name" class="pb-3" style="font-size: 17px;">Country</label>

                  <select id="country" class="form-select outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" v-model="addinfo.country" name="country">
                      <option disabled selected value="">Select Country</option>
                      <option v-for="(selectcountry, i) in countrylist" :key="index" :value="selectcountry" style="padding: 8px 12px;">{{ selectcountry }}</option>
                  </select>
              <!--   <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="country" id="country" placeholder="Philippines" v-model="addinfo.country"> -->

                    <label v-if="error.business_country" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_country}}</label>


                <label for="country_city" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px;">City</label>
                <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="city" id="city" placeholder="Makati" v-model="addinfo.city">

                    <label v-if="error.business_city" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_city}}</label>

                <label for="barangay_name" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px;">Barangay </label>
                <div class="relative">
                     <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="barangay" id="barangay" placeholder="Makati" v-model="addinfo.barangay">
                  
                    <!-- <button type="button"
                        class="flex items-center justify-between text-black w-full px-6 py-[13px] my-2 border border-black-400 outline outline-1 rounded text-start"
                        id="status-button" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true"
                        @click="toggleDropdown('barangay')">
                        <span class="text-black"
                            :class="{ 'text-gray-500': selectedBarangay === 'Select Barangay' }">{{
                            selectedBarangay }}</span>
                        <span>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2"
                                stroke="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                    d="m19.5 8.25-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
                            </svg>
                        </span>
                    </button> -->
                    <div v-if="dropdownIndex === ('barangay')"
                        class="absolute left-0 z-10 mt-1 w-[300px] origin-top-right shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-50 focus:outline-none"
                        role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="menu-button" tabindex="-1">
                        <div class="relative divide-y bg-[#132540] rounded-md" role="none">
                            <a href="#"
                                class="text-gray-700 first:rounded-t-md last:rounded-b-md bg-white block px-4 py-2 text-md hover:bg-gray-200"
                                @click="selectBarangay(item); toggleDropdown('barangay')" role="menuitem"
                                tabindex="-1" v-for="(item, index) in barangayList" :key="index"
                                :id="'status-item-' + index">{{ item
                                }}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                   <label v-if="error.business_barangay" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_barangay}}</label>
                <label for="register_address" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px;">Complete Registered
                    Address</label>
                <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="text"
                    name="address" id="address" placeholder="Philippines, Makati, Ezperanza" v-model="addinfo.address">
                    <label v-if="error.business_address" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_address}}</label>
                <label for="taxpayer_id" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px;">Tax Payer Identification
                    Number</label>
                <input class="outline outline-3 rounded  p-3 placeholder:text-s placeholder:p-1" type="tel"
                    name="tin" id="tin" placeholder="000-000-000" v-model="addinfo.tin" @input="filterNumerictin">
                    <label v-if="error.business_tin" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.business_tin}}</label>



                <h1 class="font-bold text-lg pt-11" style=" color: black; padding-bottom: 18px; font-size: 22px;">
                    Documents for Verification</h1>
                <div class="flex justify-start pl-2 w-[50rem] flex-col col-span-3">
                    <div class="flex justify-between w-[50rem]  pb-5 ">
                        <p class="font-bold text-lg pt-3  text-blue-600" style=" padding-bottom: 18px;">• Location
                            Clearance</p>
                        <div class="flex gap-4">
                          <!--   <p class="pt-3 text-red-600">Document Declined</p>            -->                  
                            <button
                                class="flex items-center">
                                   <input type="file" name="clearance" @change="upclearance">
                                  
                            </button> 

                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div style="float:right !important;">
                  <!--   <img :src="`/uploadedfiles/${showbususer.clearance}`">
                     {{showbususer.clearance}}</div>  -->
                     <img :src="'../storage/uploadedfiles/apple.jpg'">
                     
                     {{prse.clearance}}
                     </div> 
                     <div v-if="showupclearance">
                         

                     </div>

                      <label v-if="error.clearance_err" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.clearance_err}}</label>
                    <div class="flex justify-between w-[50rem]  pb-2">
                        <p class="font-bold text-lg pt-10  text-blue-600" style=" padding-bottom: 18px;">• Contract
                            of
                            Lease</p>
                        <div class="flex gap-4">
                         <!--    <p class="pt-10  text-red-600">Document Declined</p> -->
                             
                             <button
                                class="flex items-center">
                                <input type="file" name="contractlease" @change="uplease">
                               
                            </button> 
                        </div>
                        

                    </div>

                      <label v-if="error.contractlease_err" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.contractlease_err}}</label>
                     <div style="float:right !important;">{{prse.contractlease}}</div>
                    <div class="flex justify-between w-[50rem]  pb-2">
                        <p class="font-bold text-lg pt-10  text-blue-600" style=" padding-bottom: 18px;">• Business
                            Name Registration</p>
                        <div class="flex gap-4">
                           <!--  <p class="pt-10  text-red-600">Document Declined</p> -->
                            

                           <button
                                class="flex items-center">
                              
                                <input type="file" name="busregistration" @change="upregistration">
                            </button> 
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <label v-if="error.busregistration_err" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.busregistration_err}}</label>
                     <div style="float:right !important;">{{prse.busregistration}}</div>

                    <div class="flex justify-between w-[50rem]" style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <p class="font-bold text-lg pt-10  text-blue-600" style=" padding-bottom: 18px;">• Public
                            Liability Insurance</p>
                        <div class="flex gap-4">
                           <!--  <p class="pt-10  text-red-600">Document Declined</p> -->
                             <!-- <button
                                class="flex items-center px-5 mt-4 mb-4  font-bold text-gray-500 bg-white rounded border border-gray-500">
                               
                                 <input type="file" name="contractlease">
                                     <img src="@/assets/images/Modal/upload.png" alt="" class="mr-5"
                                    style="height: 30px; width: 30px;">
                               
                            </button> -->
                            <button
                                class="flex items-center">                                   
                                 <input type="file" name="liabilityinsurance" @change="upinsurance">                                   
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <label v-if="error.liabilityinsurance_err" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.liabilityinsurance_err}}</label>
                     <div style="float:right !important;">{{prse.liabilityinsurance}}</div>
                </div>

                <h1 class="font-bold text-lg " style=" color: black; padding-bottom: 5px; font-size: 22px;">
                    User Website Redirection Toggle<b class="text-red-600">*</b></h1>
                <p class="italic text-xl">To activate or deactivate a feature, simply slide the toggle switch left
                    or
                    right respectively to allow website redirection.</p>

                <label for="Toggle1" class="inline-flex items-center space-x-4 cursor-pointer pt-8 pb-8">
                    <span class="relative ">
                        <input id="Toggle1" type="checkbox" class="hidden peer" v-model="redirectChecked">
                        <div class="w-[3rem] h-6 outline outline-2 border rounded-full">
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 w-4 h-4 m-1 rounded-full border-2 border-blue-600 shadow peer-checked:right-0 peer-checked:left-auto peer-checked:bg-blue-600">
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    <span class="text-lg">Redirect to Your Website</span>
                </label>

                <div v-if="redirectChecked" class="flex flex-col justify-center">
                    <label for="redirectLink" class="font-bold">Insert Website URL:</label>
                    <input class="outline outline-1 rounded outline-blue-300 mt-1 mb-4 p-1" name="redirectweb"
                        id="redirectweb" type="url" v-model="addinfo.redirectweb">
                </div>
                 

                <hr style=" border-top: 1px solid rgb(156, 154, 154);">
                 <label v-if="error.bus_redirectweb" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.bus_redirectweb}}</label>

                        <label v-if="error.file_err"  v-for="(errors, key, index) in error.file_err" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">
                        {{errors.join(", ")}}

                        </label>


                <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                    <div class="flex justify-center gap-2">
                        <input class="mt-11 rounded-2xl border-black h-5 w-5" id="checkbox" type="checkbox"
                            v-model="acceptTerms">
                        <p class="text-lg pt-10  text-black" style=" padding-bottom: 18px;"> I accept</p>
                        <p class="font-bold text-lg pt-10 text-blue-600">Terms & Conditions</p>
                        
                    </div>

                      <label v-if="error.terms" class="pb-3 pt-4" style="font-size: 17px; color: red;">{{error.terms}}</label>
                   
                        <button
                            class="items-center p-4 w-[40%] font-bold text-white text-xl bg-[#2969D6] rounded-2xl border border-gray-500" @click="addbusinfo" v-if="submitnorec">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                         <button
                            class="items-center p-4 w-[40%] font-bold text-white text-xl bg-[#2969D6] rounded-2xl border border-gray-500" @click="updatebusinfo" v-if="updaterecord">
                           Update
                        </button>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

the main thing here is this:, the user can upload jpeg file, docs, pdf. This is where i display the file, its only on the div, not in the img. Probably the reason why its not getting the value of the data because its not in the img, or what but the file can be doc, jpeg, pdf, anyone here can give me a right idea for this? How can i get the old file without changing it? when i update only the data not the files?
<div style="float:right !important;">{{prse.clearance}}</div> 

{{prse.busregistration}}
{{prse.liabilityinsurance}}

as i understand you want users update their profile and if they didn't change the photo (or files) only given data change on backend, right?

yes thats right

well, you can update image or file after updating other data...
